# Get Vine video url and image using PHP simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, php-5.3, simple-html-dom

So i like to take vine image url and video url using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

here is a example vine url

https://vine.co/v/bjHh0zHdgZT

So i need to take this info from the URL. Form image URL:

```
<meta property="twitter:image" content="https://v.cdn.vine.co/v/thumbs/8B474922-0D0E-49AD-B237-6ED46CE85E8A-118-000000FFCD48A9C5_1.0.6.mp4.jpg?versionId=mpa1lJy2aylTIEljLGX63RFgpSR5KYNg">
```

and For the video URL

```
<meta property="twitter:player:stream" content="https://v.cdn.vine.co/v/videos/8B474922-0D0E-49AD-B237-6ED46CE85E8A-118-000000FFCD48A9C5_1.0.6.mp4?versionId=ul2ljhBV28TB1dUvAWKgc6VH0fmv8QCP">
```

I want to take only the content of the these meta tags. if anyone can help really appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: "I want to take only the content of the these meta tags". Can you show exactly what you mean (perhaps with a bit of "broken code"): "`echo myFunction($theVideoURL);` should result in `https://v.cdn.vin.co/...`" perhaps? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the lib you pointed out, I'm using native PHP DOM in this example, and it should work.

Here's a small class I created for something like that:

```
<?php

class DomFinder {
  function __construct($page) {
    $html = @file_get_contents($page);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $this->xpath = null;
    if ($html) {
      $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
      $doc->resolveExternals = true;
      @$doc->loadHTML($html);
      $this->xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
      $this->xpath->registerNamespace("html", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
    }
  }

  function find($criteria = NULL, $getAttr = FALSE) {
    if ($criteria && $this->xpath) {
      $entries = $this->xpath->query($criteria);
      $results = array();
      foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        if (!$getAttr) {
          $results[] = $entry->nodeValue;
        } else {
          $results[] = $entry->getAttribute($getAttr);
        }
      }
      return $results;
    }
    return NULL;
  }

  function count($criteria = NULL) {
    $items = 0;
    if ($criteria && $this->xpath) {
      $entries = $this->xpath->query($criteria);
      foreach ($entries as $entry) {
        $items++;
      }
    }
    return $items;
  }

}
```

To use it you can try:

```
$url = "https://vine.co/v/bjHh0zHdgZT";
$dom = new DomFinder($url);
$content_cell = $dom->find("//meta[@property='twitter:player:stream']", 'content');
print $content_cell[0];
```

Comment: Have you tested with this code and url? Notice I used a url you provide and captured the video using `property='twitter:player:stream` if you used a different url, maybe you should change for the other property.

Comment: I've tested it few minutes ago, with this code, using command line php version 5.3.26, but used to do the same using php 5.2.